# Perl Inline::Java. How to get Classpath environment variable at compilation time?

Tags: java, perl, environment-variables, classpath

I am writing a Perl script which uses the module Inline::Java. 
Including external libraries by hardcoding the CLASSPATH configuration option like

```
   use Inline (
        Java      => 'DATA',
        CLASSPATH => '/way/to/classes:/way/to/Jar.jar:.',
);
```

works.  But  using the environment variable CLASSPATH by writing

```
use Inline (
    Java      => 'DATA',
    CLASSPATH => $ENV{CLASSPATH},
);
```

doesn´t work (maybe because %ENV is set at runtime??). Wrapping the whole thing in an BEGIN block i.e. trying to write 'use' explicitly

```
   BEGIN {    
        require Inline(
            Java      => 'DATA',
            CLASSPATH => $ENV{CLASSPATH},
        );
}
```

didn't work as well (as the above code led to a compilation error). Does anybody has an idea how I can use the CLASSPATH environment variable in Inline::Java?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$inline1 = "use Inline (    Java      => 'DATA',    CLASSPATH => $ENV{CLASSPATH},)";
print $inline1;
eval $inline1;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tracked down the error. I must admit that it is a bit embarrassing, but the CLASSPATH environment variable wasn't set correctly. That means the second example with $ENV{CLASSPATH} works fine.